# DotNet LINQ: What is group.key after doing xxx.GroupBy(x => x.VendorName)

Tags: .net, linq, key, grouping

In general what is the .Key property set to?

In my example below, the Key seems to be blank.  At least it's not the vendorName as was expected.

I think I can get vendorName on the items when I loop, but why isn't it on the group level, or if it is there, where is it?

```
    int poItemsCount = 0;
    foreach (var item in linqQuery)
    {
        poItemsCount++;
        webPOInfo info = new webPOInfo(item.qVendorName, item.qSku, item.qTransID, item.qSize, item.qQty);
        lstPOInfo.Add(info);
    }


    //loop through each vendor name group
    var linqGroups = lstPOInfo.GroupBy(x => x.VendorName);
```

Looping through the results:

```
    foreach (var group in linqGroups)
    {
        //for each group, we need to create a PO header
        Logging.logMessage("Creating a PO for Vendor: " + group.Key, trcProgramName, trcProgGuid, trcCorrGuid, trcKey, "4201", null);
    ...etc
    }
```

Trace shows this:

> Creating a PO for Vendor:

Comment: The key should be whatever the `VendorName` property returns. What happens if you loop through `lstPOInfo` and log the VendorName of each PO?

Comment: Almost certain item.qVendorName going in is never blank or null.  I can check tomorrow when I log back in to work.

Comment: The code is in production and working except for the Trace statement.  It stores PO's into a database, one per Vendor.  If a web customer orders 5 items from 3 vendors, it creates 3 POs, for for each Vendor. The database inserts get the Vendor from another sub-loop thru items within the group-loop.

Comment: Yes, confirmed VendorName is definitely has a name in it.

Comment: Okay, maybe there is apparently some edge case where VendorName is not there.  I checked trace history in both test and production, and the group.key does normally work.  just tricky to maybe re-create on test system.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new object after grouping.

```
lstPOInfo.GroupBy(x => x.VendorName, (key, webPoInfoCollection) => new { Key = key, objectCollection = webPoInfoCollection });
```

Here is how to loop through the group data.

```
    foreach (var groupObj in linqGroups)
    {
        //for each group, we need to create a PO header
        Logging.logMessage("Creating a PO for Vendor: " + groupObj.Key, trcProgramName, trcProgGuid, trcCorrGuid, trcKey, "4201", null);

        foreach (var webPo in groupObj.objectCollection)
        { 
         ...etc
        }

        ...etc
    }
```

Comment: So if I understand, you are saying the Key isn't there, unless I put it there.  I cannot assume the key is the variable on which I'm doing the GroupBy.

Comment: No, the key is already there, It just another way to check that the collection has a record with a null value in field "VendorName" @Kei's solution is work perfect.

Comment: In first gray box above, was there suppsoed to be a "var linqGroups =" to the left.  That's what I tried and got: error CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'AnonymousType#1' because 'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'.

Comment: Okay, maybe there is apparently some edge case where VendorName is not there. I checked trace history in both test and production, and the group.key does normally work. just tricky to maybe re-create on test system.